# Magento 2 Duplicate Orders

Tags: magento2, orders, duplicate

I'm getting an strange issue in Magento 2.2.7.

Some of the orders are duplicating despite us only receiving one payment.

It is the exact same order information except for the order number (which increments by 1 every time) and the time (about 5 - 10 seconds between each order) which I think might indicate someone pushing the "Place Order" button multiple times.

This seems to be happening at random and doesn't seem to be confined to a single product or payment method.

I was wondering if there was a way to resolve this error and stop us receiving multiple versions of the same order.

Comment: you will have to debug this and provide us more information. we can't help you like this

Comment: Hi. I'm quite new to Magento are there any instructions about how to debug a problem like this?

Comment: @CJNotts i have recently solve this type error in magento1  this issue is start your custom extension place order event or controller

Comment: Your all order status is pending right? if yes then check payment method and try to place order with that payment method you can see error in checkout

Comment: do tthis 2 orders have the same invoices?

Comment: Hi. No they don't. Each duplicate order has it's own invoice.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: No I'm afraid it's completely random

Comment: Please note that the accepted solution uses the ```ObjectManager``` instance explicitly which is something that needs to be avoided at all costs and instead we should make use of dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution over GIT :

Create an observer `sales_order_place_before` as below:

app/code/TB/FixDuplicateOrder/Observer/OrderPlacebefore.php

```
<?php
namespace TB\FixDuplicateOrder\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderPlacebefore implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_responseFactory;
protected $_url;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
) {
    $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    $this->_url = $url;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $quoteID = $order->getQuoteId();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order');
    $selectedTime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $endTime = strtotime("-15 seconds", strtotime($selectedTime));
    $last15Sec = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $endTime);

    echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$tableName."` WHERE `quote_id` = ".$quoteID." and `created_at` >= '$last15Sec'";
    if($result = $connection->fetchRow($sql)){
        $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
        exit();
    }
    //var_dump($result);
    //echo  "Hello Testing ";
    //die();
}
```

Reference URL : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13952

Comment: Thanks, just dealing with another issue at the moment but I'll give that a go once I can and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for you.

If there are no errors from Magento logs (`var/log/...`), we need to check the web server log.

For example, for apache log

We can use `tail` command to check live error log:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log -n 100
```

In the past, I faced with the email error. The order was created before sending the email. That caused the duplicate info Orders:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | grep "mail"
```

vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php

[image]