# Checkout.com Payment Gateway error "Transaction has been declined. Please try again later."

Tags: magento2, error, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

[image]

> Transaction has been declined. Please try again later.

Checkout.com

In Magento 2, when trying to **place order** using **checkout.com** payment gateway with **sandbox** credentials getting above error

Comment: Please check your error logs (after turning on the debug mode in module) and maybe check checkout.com dashboard for error code

Comment: May be related to https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/262089/33057